# How to use Mongoose save method in Express POST route

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I am new to Express and Node and have a problem I do not understand.  I have defined two different Express routes to take a POST request for two different Mongoose data models.  One works fine and return properly, the other one returns a status of 204 in the Heroku logs and then times out, like the save is not even executing...

Here is the "Yak" model and associated POST route which saves the object and returns the expected result back to my ANgular client:

Model definition:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var YakSchema   = new Schema({
catagory: String,
loc: {
    type: [Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
    index: '2d'      // create the geospatial index
},
yakName:String,
yakDescription:String,
yakPhone:String,
yakOwner:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Yak', YakSchema);
```

And the POST route

```
router.route('/yaks')

.post(function(req, res) {
    var yak = new Yak();

    //First, need to get lat, lng from the address
    var addressString = req.body.city + ", " + req.body.street + ", " + req.body.state + ", " + req.body.postalcode;
    geocoder.geocode(addressString, function (err, data) {

        //error handling needed
        if (err){
            res.status(500).json({
                status:500,
                error:err
            });
            res.end();
        }

        var coord = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
        var lat = coord.lat;
        var lng = coord.lng;

        //Second, use the Model to save the yak with a geoJSON point

        yak.catagory = req.body.catagory;
        yak.loc = [lng, lat];
        yak.yakName = req.body.yakName;
        yak.yakDescription = req.body.yakDescription;
        yak.yakPhone = req.body.yakPhone;
        yak.yakOwner = req.body.yakOwner;
        yak.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500);
                res.json({
                    status: 500,
                    error: err
                });
                res.end();
            }
            else {
                res.json({
                    status: 200,
                    yak: yak
                });
                res.end();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the User model and user route which does NOT work

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
password: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And the POST route

```
   router.route('/users')
    .post(function(req, res) {


    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.password);


    var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    console.log(user);

    user.save(function(err){

        if (err) {
            res.status(500);
            res.json({
                status: 500,
                error: err
            });
            res.end();
        }
        else {
            res.json({
                status: 200,
                user: user
            });
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```

The only difference I see is that the save method for the "yak" route is wrapped in a callback for a previously executed method that geocodes a location.  THe User route is not in a call back.

This "feels" to me to have something to do with the Asynchronous nature of node but being new I am not sure.  Any help is greatly appreciuated

**EDIT***

Here is the result of the console .log in the POST route but before the save.  I did add a console.log inside the save but it never gets logged out...

Here is the result of the console.log of the username and password INSIDE the POST route but before the save.  I did add a console.log to the save method and it never got called....

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS     path="/api/users" host=frozen-       
peak-5921.herokuapp.com request_id=6230237d-7adc-4a51-8a26-03da99f8b7e3    
fwd="74.202.146.157" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=204 bytes=289
 app[web.1]: asd
 app[web.1]: me@mail.com
 app[web.1]: { password: 'asd',
 app[web.1]:   username: 'me@mail.com',
 app[web.1]:   _id: 5612e098a7f49c1100000001 }
 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST 
path="/api/users" host=frozen-peak-5921.herokuapp.com request_id=f6c0fde8-   
c2e4-49e5-ad65-ba6afed3b731 fwd="74.202.146.157" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 
service=30001ms status=503 byte
```

Comment: You don't need to use res.end() since res.json() calls res.end() internally.  Can you add some console.log() to your user.save function to see if there's any err or if it even gets there

Comment: The callback won't make a difference, it would only be a problem if you were trying to use a result outside the callback. Do you see the username and password logged correctly?

Comment: Here is the result of the console.log of the username and password INSIDE the POST route but before the save.  I did add a console.log to the save method and it never got called....

Comment: See my EDIT.  I added the result of the console.log in the POST and before the save, you can see it works.  I have added a console.log INSIDE the save and result never gets logged..

Comment: Hmm, this definitely sounds like a Mongoose problem, have you got any data in your Mongo collection? It may be worth clearing it out and seeing if that makes the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, WOW....  So I am using a MongoLab sandbox instance on Heroku.  On September 30th, MongoLab updated all their sandbox instances of MongoDB. Once I changed my package.json file mongoose dependency to "*", did an npm install to install the latest version of mongoose and redeployed to Heroku, it all works.  So this was caused by in incompatibility between the MongoDB version and the mongoose version.

Some sort of meaningful error handling to that effect would of been nice....